# Как сохранить результат выполнения js кода после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть 2 кнопки, которые переключают видимость каталога из формата плитки в список и наоборот.
Сейчас, когда перезагружается страница браузера(например переход на 2 страницу каталога) или когда применяются Ajax фильтры и они обновляют содержимое страницы, то каталог всегда возвращается в изначальное положение. Как мне сделать так, что бы выбор посетителя сохранялся?

```js
function btnTiles(){
    const productList = document.querySelector('.catalog>#product__list');
    productList.classList.remove('product__list');
    productList.classList.add('product__tiles');
    
    localStorage.setItem("myKey",JSON.stringify(productList));
}

function btnList(){
    const productList = document.querySelector('.catalog>#product__list');
    productList.classList.add('product__list');
    productList.classList.remove('product__tiles');
}
```

Comment: Ну сохранить что-то в браузере можно только используя localstorage, sessionStorage ну или куки, на худой конец)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте вместо localStorage - sessionStorage или cookies.

Вот примерно то что Вам должно подойти.

```js
function btnTiles() {
    const productList = document.querySelector('.catalog>#product__list');
    productList.classList.remove('product__list');
    productList.classList.add('product__tiles');
    sessionStorage.setItem('myKey', 'tiles_view');
}

function btnList() {
    const productList = document.querySelector('.catalog>#product__list');
    productList.classList.add('product__list');
    productList.classList.remove('product__tiles');
    sessionStorage.setItem('myKey', 'list_view');
}

// запускать при загрузке страницы
function initBtnView() {

    const view = sessionStorage.getItem("myKey")
    
    if(view === 'tiles_view') {
      btnTiles();
    } else if(view === 'list_view') {
      btnList();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Почему "вместо"?

Comment: Не работает ни с sessionStorage ни с cookies.

Comment: На чем Вы пишите - чистый js или SPA (react,vue и тд) ?

Comment: На чистом js пишу.

Comment: Отредактировал Ваш код, смотрите выше плз. А что используется еще, имею ввиду на backend (php, python и тд.)?

Comment: Теперь при обновлении страницы работает, но когда Ajax фильтры обновляют каталог, слетает внешний вид каталога в значение по умолчанию. В backend php. Это сайт на Wordpress